# how can i return response from php weeb page in ajax and save it in my variable

Tags: javascript

how can i return response from web page in ajax and save it in my variable

this is my code

```
      let state
function ajax(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
ajax("./code.php")
    .then(function(result) {
        state=result;
    })
    .catch(function() {
    });
console.log(state)
```

state is undefined
why ?

Comment: You seem to be missing some context. You've got `state` and `this.state`.  What does `this` refer to in your console.log?

Comment: @jmargolisvt ok i changed it But nothing happened

Comment: Check my codes if possible. thank you

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you change anything. I'm suggesting that you haven't provided enough information regarding context.  In general though, I think you should take a look at the examples provided here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand how async process going on at javascript.

When your js codes run by browser it start to execute lines up to bottom. But if there is a async process, it will execute when the process is done..

```js
let state; // execute immediately

ajax(...)
  .then(res => state = res); // execute the code when it gets the response from server

console.log(state); // execute immediately. state is declared but not defined yet. it will defined when request is done
```

You need to move your logic inside of `then` callback to take advantage of async functions.

But if you are insist to make sync http request, the `open` method of XmlHttpRequest takes boolean as third parameter which is change type of the process async to sync.

```js
 xhr.open('GET', url, false); // false mean send synchronous request
 xhr.send();
```

then you can get response using responseText

```js
console.log(xhr.responseText); // no promises needed
```

But this approach is very bad practise and it will block the executing rest of the code until the request is done

Answer (score 0):

`state` is undefined on the last line of your code, because your ajax function returns a promise, which is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous). What this means is that `console.log(state)` will be called before `state = result`. You can check this by adding a console.log('state updated') inside of your `Promise.then` callback.

In order to get the updated value of `state` and be able to use it, one approach would be to call a callback when the request is successful:

```js
ajax("./code.php")
  .then(function(result) {
    state=result;
    onCodeSuccess()
  })
  .catch(function() {
  });
    
function onCodeSuccess() {
  console.log(state)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML; this means that the request does not halt code execution and the `console.log` is executed long before the response is returned. You can only access the variable result in the `then` callback.

```
ajax("./code.php")
    .then(function(result) {
        state=result;
        console.log(state);
});
```